# SQLite: selectall_arrayref speed question

Tags: performance, perl, sqlite, dbi

Is there a difference in speed between these two modi?

```
selectall_arrayref( "SELECT * FROM $table", { Slice => { a => 1, b => 1 } } );
```

---

```
selectall_arrayref( "SELECT a, b FROM $table", { Slice => {} } );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because the `Slice` is doing post-processing on client side. So latter example will send only columns `a` and `b` in record-set. If there is more columns in the `$table`, latter call would be less expensive and faster.